# Using "php -i | grep "Loaded plugins|PHP Version " | tail -n2", nothing show

Tags: php, mysql

I hear about that PHP 7.4.x supports MySQL 8. And read this article https://www.ma-no.org/en/networking/databases/mysql-8-0-is-now-fully-supported-in-php-7-4, I follow its instructions and use command:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded plugins|PHP Version " | tail -n2
```

But nothing appear.

I try again this:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded plugins|PHP Version "
```

Nothing appear either.

I try to use

```
php -i
```

This time there are a lot of lines and it is rather difficult to check each of them.

So why "php -i | grep "Loaded plugins|PHP Version " | tail -n2" not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell **grep** to interpret "Loaded plugins|PHP Version " as an extended regular expression.

```
 php -i | grep  -E "Loaded plugins|PHP Version" | tail -n2

PHP Version => 8.0.8
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
```

Comment: Alternately, `egrep` has this option turned on by default.